# Connecting tables with foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

List the number of employees who work in each department.

```
SELECT DEPT_NO AS "DEPARTMENT NO" ,COUNT(ID_NO) AS "NO OF EMPLOYEE"
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY DEPT_NO
ORDER BY DEPT_NO
```

which produces the following results:

```
DEPARTMENT NO NO OF EMPLOYEE
------------- --------------
            1              4
            2              3
            3              3
            5              8
```

It works fine till here. But when I try to combine with another table using the foreign key it throws an error:

```
SELECT E.DEPT_NO AS "DEPARTMENT NO" , D.DEPT_NAME AS "DEPARTMENT NAME" ,COUNT(E.ID_NO) AS "NO OF EMPLOYEE"
FROM EMPLOYEES E,DEPTS D
WHERE E.DEPT_NO=D.DEPT_NO
GROUP BY DEPT_NO
ORDER BY DEPT_NO

ORDER BY DEPT_NO
         *
ERROR AT LINE 5
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Can anyone help me find the error in my code?

Comment: Foreign keys are constraints used to ensure data consistency.

Comment: Qualify all the columns, e.g. `E.DEPT_NO` instead of just `DEPT_NO`.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Typing in **ALL CAPS** is hard to read, and it's considered **SHOUTING** at your audience - which is just plain rude and offensive - **STOP THAT** right now!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not use images to post code and data; instead, [learn to use markdown appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). See the page at [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for further information. Others have commented on the use of ALL CAPS, etc. Above all, please try not to be disheartened by this reaction to what is, after all, only your second question. It's a matter of learning the culture here at StackOverflow, and that can take some time and practice.

Answer (score 2):

Correction in your query:

```
GROUP BY E.DEPT_NO
ORDER BY E.DEPT_NO
```

Change above two lines in your query since SQL is not able to recognize to which DEPT_NO Column you are referencing.

**CAUSE OF ERROR:**

> A column name used in a join exists in more than one table and is thus
>   referenced ambiguously. In a join, any column name that occurs in more
>   than one of the tables must be prefixed by its table name when
>   referenced. The column should be referenced as TABLE.COLUMN or
>   TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN. For example, if tables EMP and DEPT are being
>   joined and both contain the column DEPTNO, then all references to
>   DEPTNO should be prefixed with the table name, as in EMP.DEPTNO or
>   E.DEPTNO.

For more info follow the below link:

> http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm

Change Your Query:

```
SELECT E.Dept_No AS 'Department NUmber', D.Dept_Name AS 'Department Name',
COUNT(E.ID_NO) AS 'No. Of Employee'
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Department D
ON E.DEPT_No = D.Dept_No
GROUP BY E.DEPT_No,D.Dept_Name
ORDER BY E.DEPT_No
```